# Finding Item with specific value, moving and deleting it. c#,linq

Tags: c#, linq

This program should generate numbers, then choose unique numbers and count how many times this number appears during generation - it is working for now.

Now I need to choose eg.5 Items with highest item.value and display them like:

name(just unique number) = value(number of apperances)

5 = 40

6 = 70
...

For now I only find Item with highest value.
Any tips how can I choose Item with highest value I've found, move it to another list, delete it from original list and then display all Items with highest values?

It's my first post since I've just started to learn programming so sorry for mistakes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Lotto_2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var generated = new List<int>();
            var random = new Random();
            var uniques = new List<int>();
            var itemList = new List<Item>();
            var maxValueList = new List<int>();

            // Random numbers generating (from 1 to 49)
            for (int i = 0; i < 2400; i++)
            {
                var number = random.Next(1, 50);
                generated.Add(number);
            }

            // Unique numbers selecting
            foreach (var number in generated)
            {
                if (!uniques.Contains(number)) uniques.Add(number);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Number of generated items: " + generated.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Unique items number: " + uniques.Count);

            // Unique number repeating count
            foreach (var unique in uniques)
            {
                var countedUniques = 0;
                foreach (var number in generated)
                {
                    if (unique == number)
                        countedUniques ++;
                }
                // Save to itemList
                var item = new Item(unique,countedUniques);
                itemList.Add(item);
            }

            var editedItemList = itemList;
            foreach (var item in itemList)
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} = {item.Value}");

            // Searching max value item
            var maxValue = editedItemList.Max( x => x.Value);
            maxValueList.Add(maxValue);
            Console.WriteLine(maxValue);
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Name { get; protected set; }
        public int Value { get; protected set; }

        public Item(int name, int value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have made a good start here, but if you improve your existing program you will find it easier to modify it to do what you want.  You are using lists, but lists are not the best data structure to solve the problem you have. Do you know what a `Dictionary` is?  Can you make a program that maintains a `Dictionary<int, int>` where the key is the unique number, and the value is the count of the number of times the unique number appears?

Comment: You can also improve your program by breaking up your `Main` method into many smaller methods.  For example, it would be better to say `var generated = GenerateList();` and then make a method `private static List<int> GenerateList() { var random = new Random(); var generated = new List<int>(); for ( ... ) { ... } return generated; }` because (1) that makes your `Main` easier to understand, and (2) it lets you improve `GenerateList` later. Break up your `Main` into many smaller methods, each of which does one thing *extremely well*.

Comment: @mjwills: That's a good point -- which speaks to my larger point.  **By isolating implementation decisions into methods we can then attempt to improve those methods independently**. Upon code reviewing we might note that multiple calls in close succession could generate the same list, and then consider different ways to mitigate the problem. "Make the `Random` static" would be one, but there are many possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ has many operations that can help solve this problem using only a single collection. The following example starts with a `List<int>` of generated values, calculates how many times each unique number appears, and then takes the 5 values with the most appearances. Note that the original list is actually unaffected. By design, LINQ does not modify the original collection, instead returning new collections that can be enumerated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var generated = GenerateList();

            var uniqueItems = generated
                // Groups each number by the given key (itself). Each group will contain one distinct number
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                // Creates key/value pairs. The key is the unique number. The value is the number of appearances
                .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

            Console.WriteLine("Number of generated items: " + generated.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("Unique items number: " + uniqueItems.Count);
            foreach (var item in uniqueItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
            }

            var highestFive = uniqueItems
                // Sort the items by their appearances (highest first)
                .OrderByDescending(item => item.Value)
                // Only keep the first 5 items
                .Take(5);

            Console.WriteLine("Numbers with the highest 5 occurrences");
            foreach (var item in highestFive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            }

            /* Output:
             * Number of generated items: 20
             * Unique items number: 6
             * 10 = 2
             * 25 = 3
             * 30 = 5
             * 45 = 4
             * 5 = 5
             * 15 = 1
             * Numbers with the highest 5 occurrences
             * 30
             * 5
             * 45
             * 25
             * 10
             */
        }

        private static List<int> GenerateList()
        {
            // For simplicity, using known variables
            // This function could generate any type of list you want
            return new List<int>
            {
                10, 25, 30, 45, 30, 45, 25, 30, 25, 30, 5, 5, 15, 30, 45, 10, 45, 5, 5, 5
            };
        }
    }
}
```

---

An alternative method would be to calculate the frequency of each number as they are generated using a `Dictionary<int, int>`, as [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has already suggested. The following example uses a Dictionary and therefore doesn't need to perform the `GroupBy` operation of the previous example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var generated = 0;
            var random = new Random();
            var items = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2400; i++)
            {
                var number = random.Next(1, 50);
                generated++; // Keep track of how many have been generated

                if (items.ContainsKey(number))
                {
                    // If the number is not unique, increase its appearances by 1
                    items[number]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the number is unique, set its appearances to 1
                    items.Add(number, 1);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Number of generated items: " + generated);
            Console.WriteLine("Unique items number: " + items.Count);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} = {item.Value}");
            }

            var highestFive = items
                // Sort the items by their appearances (highest first)
                .OrderByDescending(item => item.Value)
                // Only keep the first 5 items
                .Take(5);

            Console.WriteLine("Numbers with the highest 5 occurrences");
            foreach (var item in highestFive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first proposition seems the most suitable for me. Thanks for this, I must admit that i have no idea I can use Dictionary for this but as I mentioned - I'm new in programming and I have a lot to lern.